# Can I submit multiple tcomb forms with one onPress?

Tags: javascript, forms, react-native, tcomb-form-native, tcomb

I'm building a React Native app and using the tomb-form-native library for my forms.  In one of my screens, I loop through an array of types and output a form for each type:

```
{my_types.map(ob =>
  <View key={++i}>
    <Text>{ob.type} #{ob.num}</Text>
    <Form 
      ref={(c) => { 
        this.form = {}
        this.form[ob.type] = c 
      }} 
      type={_formType(this, ob.type)} 
      options={_formOptions(ob.type)} 
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
    />
  </View>
)}

<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

But when I try to get the submitted values in my onPress function, it doesn't work for multiple types.  It works for one type if I only call getValue() once:

```
input = this.form['my_type'].getValue()
console.log(input) // I see in my debugger that it works.
```

But if I try to get the input for two or more types, I don't see anything in the log...

```
input = this.form['my_type'].getValue()
console.log(input) // Nothing. It doesn't work.

input2 = this.form['my_other_type'].getValue()
console.log(input2) // Nothing here either.
```

Is it possible to use the tcomb library to submit multiple forms with one onPress?  Maybe it's the way I call my onPress function in the onPress property of TouchableHighlight?

**UPDATE**

This simplified onPress function suggests my form ref is only working the last time through the loop.  If my loop has two items...

```
  onPress() {

    let input = this.form[1]
    console.log(input) // Undefined.

    let input2 = this.form[2]
    console.log(input2) // Object.

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be possible.  If I use an array to track the form refs, it works:

```
this.form = []

return (
...

{a.map(ob =>
  <View key={++i} style={s}>
    <Text>{ob.type} #{ob.num}</Text>
    <Form 
      ref={(c) => { 
        this.form.push(c)
      }} 
      key={i}
      type={_formType(this, ob.type)} 
      options={_formOptions(ob.type)} 
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
    />
  </View>
)}

<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

And here is a simplified onPress...

```
onPress() {
  let tF = this.form
  tF.forEach(function(f) {
    if (f) { // First two times through the loop, f is null, in my application.
      console.log(f.getValue()) // It works!
    }
  })
}
```